# custom listview save selected item position

Tags: android, listview, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I create a custom listview.

I want to select any item using another button click or something views click.

Already I tried via these code for custom selection.

And I also want to get previous selected item  on resume.

```
listView.setItemChecked(2,true);
listView.setSelection(2);
listView.requestFocus();
```

But everytime , I failed.

I used this method to create custom listview.

[Android ListView with Custom Adapter Example Tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial)

Advance Thanks .

Comment: define failed what's your error log ?

Comment: There is no error. But not selecting.

Comment: then you need put more code in there. it's not clear where the problem is

Answer (score 0):

For `setItemChecked` to work, your list items need to be `Checkable`; you can, for example use `CheckedTextView` (at the top level of the item view, no further layout around it).

For `setSelection` to work, you need to use it inside a `Runnable`, like so:

```
listView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        listView.setSelection(2);
    }
});
```

In both cases, don't ask why.

For a selection to become visible, you can put a statelist in the background attribute of your list item.